# How can I animate this image in a td using jQuery and/or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<td id="display5" class="displayableCell" style="border: 0px none; width: 120px;">
<span id="name5">Photo Name</span>
<br>
<img id="img5" height="auto" width="120px" src="/Home/GetPhoto/53">
</td>
```

I have tried many things to no avail.  This is my most recent attempt, which minimizes the image, but does not move it to the right which is the whole goal here.  *How to animate it to the right, outside of the td area.*

```
var target = "#img" + Displayable.count;
$(target).animate({ "left": "+=240px", "width": "-=120px" }, "fast");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to animate the `left` property, you'll want to add `position: absolute` to your image.  That's likely why it wasn't moving to the right.

Comment: Don't forget the closing parenthesis. :)

Comment: @TravisJ - I added an update to my answer.  My apologies for not reading your question fully enough to see that it was already resizing, but not moving.

Comment: @TravisJ, I believe you have to set the position style. Try `relative`.

Comment: @TravisJ - I though position:absolute would give it an absolute position relative to its parent.

Comment: Position:absolute was the answer, I had tried it but was applying it to the wrong place (the td)! lol, thanks for the effort guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead animate `left` attribute you can modify a `margin-left` with the same result but you do not have change a `position` attribute however image should be animated properly.

```
$(target).animate({ "margin-left": "+=240px", "width": "-=120px" }, "fast");
```

Comment: This will work, however, changing margins affects the whole page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are not setting a `position` CSS property for the `img` elements. By default the `position` property for an element is set to `static` which makes the element ignore `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` property declarations. You need to set the element's `position` to something other than `static`.

Since you want the image to animate out of it's parent container, I suggest using `position : absolute`:

```
.displayableCell > img{
    position : absolute;
    top      : 20px;
    left     : 0;
}
```

That's all you need to change, the jQuery code you provided works fine.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PYsjz/ (click the image to see the animation)

Comment: Thank you Jasper, this was the issue but Adam had been working on it with me for a couple iterations and we came to the same conclusion so I marked his as the answer.